# Angular.js has package router and why do I need a node.js & express.js?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I like to know about that because i'm learning how to work Angular.js so I see Angular has router and Node.js with express.js too.
which is different between node and angular's router & express.js?
To this for MEAN... thank you for ur time

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Express.js, or other Node.js back-ends. You can use Angular with any back-end, or even no back-end.

Angular router is the router package for the front-end. Let's say you want to load `ContactComponent` in `/contact`, `LoginComponent` in `/login`. When you visit these URLs, the router loads corresponding component and display it in the `<router-outlet>` component, that's it. If you want to add back-end logic, like interact with DB, API... You will probably need back-end like Express.js as you've asked.